# Deserialise Yaml List of Objects

Tags: java, spring, jackson, yaml, deserialization

I have a yaml file with data that looks like this:

```
dog:
  animalId: dog00
  animalName: Dog
  animalFamily: Canidae
cat:
  animalId: cat00
  animalName: Cat
  animalFamily: Felidae
elephant:
  animalId: elpnt
  animalName: Elephant
  animalFamily: Elephantidae
...
```

(**Update**: I don't have control over the yaml file)

How can I deserialise this into a list of *'animal'* objects in Java?

My `Animal` class looks like this

```
public class Animal {
   private String animalId;
   private String animalName;
   private String animalFamily;

   // getters, setters, constructors
}
```

I am trying to use jackson as follows

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
CollectionType listType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Animal.class);

List<Animal> animals = mapper.readValue(new File("src/main/resources/animals.yaml"), listType);
```

but I get the error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of 'java.util.ArrayList<Animal>' out of START_OBJECT token
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your YAML definition does not match your object model.

The YAML definition describes a `Map` of `Animal`, whereas your object model expects a `List` of `Animal`.

Try changing your YAML file to:

```
-
  animalId: dog00
  animalName: Dog
  animalFamily: Canidae
-
  animalId: cat00
  animalName: Cat
  animalFamily: Felidae
-
  animalId: elpnt
  animalName: Elephant
  animalFamily: Elephantidae
```

Or try changing your Java code so it deserializes to a `Map<String, Animal>`.

```
Map<String, Animal> animals = mapper.readValue(new File("src/main/resources/animals.yaml"), new TypeReference<Map<String, Animal>>(){});
```

Comment: I just read your update that the YAML input cannot be changed. Ok, no problem. In that case we have to change the Java code so it matches the YAML model. Can you try deserializing to a `Map<String, Animal>` instead of a `ArrayList`?

Comment: Deseraliesing to ```Map<String, Animal>``` does the job! Thank you!!